# How to add the ID of max date to output along with all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I am new to SQL. I have this table T1.

| user | date_created | source | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paul | 12/21/2021 | Aus | India |
| john | 12/22/2021 | Aus | India |
| john | 12/23/2021 | India | Pak |
| paul | 12/24/2021 | India | Pak |
| john | 12/25/2021 | USA | Japan |
| ruby | 12/26/2021 | USA | EU |
| john | 12/27/2021 | USA | EU |
| ruby | 12/28/2021 | USA | Japan |

I want the following as as output.

| user | date_created | source | target | max_date | max_date_user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| paul | 12/21/2021 | Aus | India | 12/22/2021 | john |
| john | 12/22/2021 | Aus | India | 12/22/2021 | john |
| john | 12/23/2021 | India | Pak | 12/24/2021 | paul |
| paul | 12/24/2021 | India | Pak | 12/24/2021 | paul |
| john | 12/25/2021 | USA | Japan | 12/28/2021 | ruby |
| ruby | 12/26/2021 | USA | EU | 12/27/2021 | john |
| john | 12/27/2021 | USA | EU | 12/27/2021 | john |
| ruby | 12/28/2021 | USA | Japan | 12/28/2021 | ruby |

I need all the rows and columns in output, along with addition of 2 more columns **max_date** and **max_date_user**. I want the output of these 2 additional columns to look for max date/user based on concatenation of source and target.
I am able add and get the max_date column using the below query.

```
select 
    *,
    max(date_created) over (partition by concat(source ,target)) as "max_date"
from 
    t1
```

But for max_date_user, I am unable to get the desired output. Can anyone help me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, using `ROW_NUMBER` with pivoting logic:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source, target
                                 ORDER BY date_created DESC) rn
    FROM t1
)

SELECT user, date_created, source, target,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN date_created END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY source, target) max_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN user END) OVER
           (PARTITION BY source, target) max_date_user
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    date_created;
```

Comment: Of course, you are right, sorry